How to get access pem file which is store in resources in Spring Boot Java
I am trying to access a pem file in spring boot application. The file in locate in
src/main/resources.
It is working when I am start app in my local computer but when I push the jar file to VPS server or run with docker there it is not working.
It showing this error:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.getBytes(java.nio.charset.Charset)" because "src" is null

I have used this code to get the data:
    public PrivateKey getPrivate() throws Exception {
        ClassPathResource resource = new ClassPathResource("marchent_private.pem");
        InputStream inputStream = resource.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String content = reader.readLine();
        System.out.println(content);

        content = content.replaceAll("\\s", "");

        byte[] keyBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(content);
        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec spec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
        KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        return kf.generatePrivate(spec);
    }

So that now, How can I solve this problem?
If you want to check more you can check the project git.
Project Link

Add the COMPLETE stacktrace to the question AS TEXT so that people can tell where the exception is being thrown.

@StephenC brother I also can't find out the problem. It show that exception nothing more then it. If you want I can share the full link of github.

The reason your code doesn't show you full stack traces is stuff like this:  catch (Exception er) { System.out.println(er.getMessage()); ...   Fix ALL code you have written like that so that it prints (or better still, logs) the full stacktrace not just the exception message.  Then show us the full stacktrace.  (You shouldn't write stuff like that.  'Cos you are just making your code hard for you to debug.)

You can try to read application.properties. Do you have the same error?

I have got the problem. the problem in a data model.

It is advisable to have the configuration externalized and not include it within the .jar:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/reference/features/external-config.html#:~:text=Spring%20Boot%20lets%20you%20externalize,%2C%20and%20command%2Dline%20arguments
When you run the application in a different environment than the local one you will normally use a different command (specifying the location of the path or properties, etc..). A common way to do this is using different properties files regarding the environment:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.0.M1/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-profile-specific-properties
Example of a command with externalized properties:
java -jar /jarlocationinvm/yourjarname.jar --spring.profiles.active=prod --spring.config.location=/configlocationinvm/

